# Chocolatey: How to re-install uninstalled package before

Tags: chocolatey, choco

I'm managing software on my computer with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).
I'm in a trouble with re-installing uninstalled package.

I tried to re-install it, but nothing happens.
How can I re-install a package which I uninstalled before.

```
choco -y install ruby --version 2.2.4
choco -y uninstall ruby --version 2.2.4
choco -y install ruby --version 2.2.4
```

I suspect to fail to uninstall, I tried to list with a command "choco list -lo".
However ruby is not displayed on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by myself.
I misunderstand the commandline options.

I run chocolatey again with a command below, it was completed with no error.

```
choco install ruby --version 2.2.4 -y
```